# Set properties of multiple views at once

Tags: java, android, android-view

For example, if I have:

```
EditText A;
TextView B;
ImageView C;
```

And I want to set all their visibilities to `View.GONE`, how can I do it in a way that instead of this:

```
A.setVisibility(View.GONE);
B.setVisibility(View.GONE);
C.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I do this:

```
groupD.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

without having to put all of them in one `RelativeLayout` and then setting the `RelativeLayout` to `View.GONE`?  Is there a Java class for this? Or do I have to get a library for it?

If not, can I do it manually so I can organize my project which has 30 views? I don't want to set each group to be in its own `RelativeLayout` because all views are dependent on each other.

Comment: To do that, you would need a `ViewGroup` or a class that derives from `ViewGroup`, for example a `RelativeLayout` as you mention. Why wouldn't you want to use a `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116878/discussion-between-abappletic-and-0xdeadc0de).

Comment: I'd like it if whoever downvoted this question reconsider after I edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way will be passing the views to a single method. All of them are Views, so you can do something like this.

```
public void setViews(View view){
    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

And call the method like this:

```
setViews(editText);
```

Comment: Cool. I'll see if I could do that.

Comment: Why would I downvote a question which accepted my answer ?

Answer (score 3):

With [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) you can do:

```
@BindViews({ R.id.A, R.id.B, R.id.C })
List<View> views;

ButterKnife.apply(views, VISIBLE);
ButterKnife.apply(views, GONE);

//Action and Setter interfaces allow specifying simple behavior.

static final ButterKnife.Action<View> VISIBLE = new ButterKnife.Action<View>() {
  @Override public void apply(View view, int index) {
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }
};
static final ButterKnife.Action<View> GONE = new ButterKnife.Action<View>() {
  @Override public void set(View view, int index) {
    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
};
```

Example adapted from the website

Comment: Looks like the code for that is bigger than mine, which is pretty useless. -1

Comment: @NathanZ. I was thinking the same thing, but I stopped caring :)

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE. The day I stopped answering down voted questions. Groetjes :)

Comment: If any of you downvoted the question, please reconsider after the edit.

Comment: The idea is that you define the GONE, and VISIBLE actions once in a Util class. So then your code is only ButterKnife.apply(views, GONE);, which is shorter.